# Postfix + Dovecot login fail only in Imap

Tags: postfix, dovecot, pam, imap, sasl

sorry in advance because Im sure the problem is stupid, but after two days trying different configurations from Google and Serverfault it still not working. Im Newbie in Postfix/Dovecot

After upgrading Debian, I configured (for first time) Postfix with Dovecot.
 **Pop3 works fine now but Imap not (login fails)**

main.cf

```
    # See /usr/share/postfix/main.cf.dist for a commented, more complete version


# Debian specific:  Specifying a file name will cause the first
# line of that file to be used as the name.  The Debian default
# is /etc/mailname.
#myorigin = /etc/mailname

smtpd_banner = $myhostname ESMTP $mail_name
biff = no

# appending .domain is the MUA's job.
append_dot_mydomain = no

# Uncomment the next line to generate "delayed mail" warnings
#delay_warning_time = 4h

readme_directory = /usr/share/doc/postfix

# TLS parameters
smtpd_tls_cert_file = /etc/postfix/smtpd.cert
smtpd_tls_key_file = /etc/postfix/smtpd.key
smtpd_use_tls = no
smtpd_tls_session_cache_database = btree:${data_directory}/smtpd_scache
smtp_tls_session_cache_database = btree:${data_directory}/smtp_scache

# See /usr/share/doc/postfix/TLS_README.gz in the postfix-doc package for
# information on enabling SSL in the smtp client.

myhostname = SERVERNAME
alias_maps = hash:/etc/aliases
alias_database = hash:/etc/aliases
myorigin = /etc/mailname
mydestination = SERVERNAME.COM, localhost, localhost.localdomain
mynetworks = 127.0.0.0/8
mailbox_command =
mailbox_size_limit = 0
recipient_delimiter = +
inet_interfaces = all
inet_protocols = all
smtpd_sasl_local_domain =
broken_sasl_auth_clients = yes
smtpd_sasl_authenticated_header = yes
smtpd_recipient_restrictions = permit_mynetworks, check_sender_access hash:/etc/postfix/restricted_senders, permit_sasl_authenticated, reject_unauth_destination permit_inet_interfaces
#smtpd_recipient_restrictions = permit_mynetworks, reject_unauth_destination, permit_inet_interfaces
#smtpd_recipient_restrictions = permit_mynetworks, permit_sasl_authenticated, check_recipient_access mysql:/etc/postfix/mysql-virtual_recipient.cf, reject_unauth_destination
smtpd_tls_auth_only = no
smtp_use_tls = no
smtp_tls_note_starttls_offer = yes
smtpd_tls_CAfile = /etc/postfix/ssl/cacert.pem
smtpd_tls_loglevel = 1
smtpd_tls_received_header = yes
smtpd_tls_session_cache_timeout = 3600s
tls_random_source = dev:/dev/urandom
home_mailbox = Maildir/

smtpd_helo_required = yes
smtpd_helo_restrictions = permit_mynetworks,
 permit_sasl_authenticated,
                          reject_unauth_pipelining,
                          reject_non_fqdn_sender,
                          reject_non_fqdn_recipient,
                          reject_unknown_sender_domain,
                          reject_unknown_recipient_domain,
                          reject_unauth_destination,
                          reject_rbl_client sbl.spamhaus.org,
                          reject_rbl_client blackholes.wirehub.net,
                          reject_rbl_client bl.spamcop.net,
                          permit


content_filter = amavis:[127.0.0.1]:10024
receive_override_options = no_address_mappings
html_directory = /usr/share/doc/postfix/html
message_size_limit = 30720000
virtual_alias_maps = proxy:mysql:/etc/postfix/mysql-virtual_forwardings.cf, mysql:/etc/postfix/mysql-virtual_email2email.cf
virtual_alias_domains =
virtual_mailbox_domains = proxy:mysql:/etc/postfix/mysql-virtual_domains.cf
virtual_mailbox_maps = proxy:mysql:/etc/postfix/mysql-virtual_mailboxes.cf
virtual_mailbox_base = /var/vmail
virtual_uid_maps = static:5000
virtual_gid_maps = static:5000
transport_maps = proxy:mysql:/etc/postfix/mysql-virtual_transports.cf
#relay_domains = mysql:/etc/postfix/mysql-virtual_relaydomains.cf
#virtual_create_maildirsize = yes
#virtual_maildir_extended = yes
#virtual_mailbox_limit_inbox = yes
virtual_mailbox_limit_maps = proxy:mysql:/etc/postfix/mysql-virtual_mailbox_limit_maps.cf
#virtual_mailbox_limit_override = yes
#virtual_maildir_limit_message = "The user you are trying to reach is over quota."
#virtual_overquota_bounce = yes
proxy_read_maps = $local_recipient_maps $mydestination $virtual_alias_maps $virtual_alias_domains $virtual_mailbox_maps $virtual_mailbox_domains $relay_recipient_maps $relay_domains $canonical_maps $sender_canonical_maps $recipient_canonical_maps $relocated_maps $transport_maps $mynetworks $virtual_mailbox_limit_maps
#smtpd_sender_restrictions = check_sender_access mysql:/etc/postfix/mysql-virtual_sender.cf
# smtpd_client_restrictions = check_client_access mysql:/etc/postfix/mysql-virtual_client.cf
maildrop_destination_concurrency_limit = 1
maildrop_destination_recipient_limit = 1
virtual_transport = maildrop
header_checks = regexp:/etc/postfix/header_checks
mime_header_checks = regexp:/etc/postfix/mime_header_checks
nested_header_checks = regexp:/etc/postfix/nested_header_checks
body_checks = regexp:/etc/postfix/body_checks

## local ###
disable_vrfy_command = yes
smtpd_banner = $myhostname
#smtpd_client_restrictions = permit_mynetworks permit_inet_interfaces
smtpd_tls_security_level = may
smtpd_sasl_auth_enable = yes
smtpd_client_restrictions = permit_mynetworks permit_inet_interfaces permit_tls_all_clientcerts



smtpd_sasl_type = dovecot
smtpd_sasl_path = private/auth
smtpd_sasl_security_options = noanonymous
#smtpd_relay_restrictions = permit_mynetworks, permit_sasl_authenticated, check_recipient_access mysql:/etc/postfix/mysql-virtual_recipient.cf, reject_unauth_destinatination
```

postconf -a

```
cyrus
dovecot
```

postconf -n

```
alias_database = hash:/etc/aliases
alias_maps = hash:/etc/aliases
append_dot_mydomain = no
biff = no
body_checks = regexp:/etc/postfix/body_checks
broken_sasl_auth_clients = yes
config_directory = /etc/postfix
content_filter = amavis:[127.0.0.1]:10024
disable_vrfy_command = yes
header_checks = regexp:/etc/postfix/header_checks
home_mailbox = Maildir/
html_directory = /usr/share/doc/postfix/html
inet_interfaces = all
inet_protocols = all
mailbox_command =
mailbox_size_limit = 0
maildrop_destination_concurrency_limit = 1
maildrop_destination_recipient_limit = 1
message_size_limit = 30720000
mime_header_checks = regexp:/etc/postfix/mime_header_checks
mydestination = SERVERNAME.COM, localhost, localhost.localdomain
myhostname = SERVERNAME.COM
mynetworks = 127.0.0.0/8
myorigin = /etc/mailname
nested_header_checks = regexp:/etc/postfix/nested_header_checks
proxy_read_maps = $local_recipient_maps $mydestination $virtual_alias_maps $virtual_alias_domains $virtual_mailbox_maps $virtual_mailbox_domains $relay_recipient_maps $relay_domains $canonical_maps $sender_canonical_maps $recipient_canonical_maps $relocated_maps $transport_maps $mynetworks $virtual_mailbox_limit_maps
readme_directory = /usr/share/doc/postfix
receive_override_options = no_address_mappings
recipient_delimiter = +
smtp_tls_note_starttls_offer = yes
smtp_tls_session_cache_database = btree:${data_directory}/smtp_scache
smtp_use_tls = no
smtpd_banner = $myhostname
smtpd_client_restrictions = permit_mynetworks permit_inet_interfaces permit_tls_all_clientcerts
smtpd_helo_required = yes
smtpd_helo_restrictions = permit_mynetworks, permit_sasl_authenticated, reject_unauth_pipelining, reject_non_fqdn_sender, reject_non_fqdn_recipient, reject_unknown_sender_domain, reject_unknown_recipient_domain, reject_unauth_destination, reject_rbl_client sbl.spamhaus.org, reject_rbl_client blackholes.wirehub.net, reject_rbl_client bl.spamcop.net, permit
smtpd_recipient_restrictions = permit_mynetworks, check_sender_access hash:/etc/postfix/restricted_senders, permit_sasl_authenticated, reject_unauth_destination permit_inet_interfaces
smtpd_sasl_auth_enable = yes
smtpd_sasl_authenticated_header = yes
smtpd_sasl_local_domain =
smtpd_sasl_path = private/auth
smtpd_sasl_security_options = noanonymous
smtpd_sasl_type = dovecot
smtpd_tls_CAfile = /etc/postfix/ssl/cacert.pem
smtpd_tls_auth_only = no
smtpd_tls_cert_file = /etc/postfix/smtpd.cert
smtpd_tls_key_file = /etc/postfix/smtpd.key
smtpd_tls_loglevel = 1
smtpd_tls_received_header = yes
smtpd_tls_security_level = may
smtpd_tls_session_cache_database = btree:${data_directory}/smtpd_scache
smtpd_tls_session_cache_timeout = 3600s
smtpd_use_tls = no
tls_random_source = dev:/dev/urandom
transport_maps = proxy:mysql:/etc/postfix/mysql-virtual_transports.cf
virtual_alias_domains =
virtual_alias_maps = proxy:mysql:/etc/postfix/mysql-virtual_forwardings.cf, mysql:/etc/postfix/mysql-virtual_email2email.cf
virtual_gid_maps = static:5000
virtual_mailbox_base = /var/vmail
virtual_mailbox_domains = proxy:mysql:/etc/postfix/mysql-virtual_domains.cf
virtual_mailbox_limit_maps = proxy:mysql:/etc/postfix/mysql-virtual_mailbox_limit_maps.cf
virtual_mailbox_maps = proxy:mysql:/etc/postfix/mysql-virtual_mailboxes.cf
virtual_transport = maildrop
virtual_uid_maps = static:5000
```

var/log/mail.info

Feb 11 22:02:00 servername dovecot: auth-worker(9414): pam(user@servername.com,XXX): pam_authenticate() failed: Authentication failure (password mismatch?) (given password: xxx)
Feb 11 22:02:02 servername dovecot: imap-login: Disconnected (auth failed, 3 attempts in 26 secs): user=, method=PLAIN, rip=XXX, lip=XXX, session=

Comment: Pd: port 143 is open

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, solved. The problem was Pop3 was still working with old program Courier (even the logs shows was over Dovecot...) and Imap over Dovecot. Dovecot was difficult to config because the mail bd was made by hand, so I finally installed courier-imap (thats remove Dovecot-imap) and the server was recovered.